# Placeholder for form elements using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, placeholder

Well to begin i would like to mention that the aim of this question is not to ask how it is done but rather understand why the way i did it works.

I wanted to create placeholder texts for form elements and while playing with jquery i came up with the following code:

```
function placehold(id,placeholder) // id of element and placeholder text
{
    $("#"+id).val(placeholder); //initialize form field

    $("#"+id).focusin(function() //on focus
    {
        if ($(this).val()==(placeholder))
        {
            $(this).val(null); 
            /*if input's value is placeholder then empty
              input and wait for value */
        }        
    });


    $("#"+id).focusout(function() //on lost focus
    {
        if ($(this).val()==(""))
        {
            $(this).val(placeholder); //reset val to placeholder text if empty
        }        
    });
}
```

And this will work even if i call the function on several fields, like,

```
placehold('uname','Please enter a username');
placehold('pword','Please enter a password);
placehold('email','Please enter an email address');
```

in the above case it will work in all 3 textboxes as expected, and herein lies my question:
Where are the different placeholders stored during runtime? is an instance of the function kept for each field it is bound to? if yes Would that have any implications on performance in the long run?

Thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is an instance of the function kept for each field it is bound to?

Yes. For every time you call `placehold()`, new event handler functions are created. The values of `id` and `placeholder` are kept as part of the closures you create.

> if yes Would that have any implications on performance in the long run?

The way you did it, there is a little overhead associated with every element that you call `placehold()` on. I would not worry about that, though, it really is negligible.

Nicer would be to re-use the event-handling functions:

```
function placeholderEmpty() { 
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.val() == $this.data("placeholder") ) {
        $this.val(""); 
    }        
}
function placeholderDefault() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.val() == "" ) {
        $this.val( $this.data("placeholder") ); 
    }        
}

function placehold(id,placeholder) {
  $("#"+id).data("placeholder", placeholder) 
  .focusin(placeholderEmpty)
  .focusout(placeholderDefault)
  .trigger("focusout");
}
```

The next step would be a plugin (*note the use of another closure*):

```
$.fn.extend({
  placehold: function () {
    var placeholderEmpty   = function () { /* ... */ };
    var placeholderDefault = function () { /* ... */ };

    return function(placeholder) {
      this.data("placeholder", placeholder) 
      .focusin(placeholderEmpty)
      .focusout(placeholderDefault)
      .trigger("focusout");
      return this; 
    }
  }();
});
```

use as

```
$('#uname').placehold('Please enter a username');
$('#pword').placehold('Please enter a password');
$('#email').placehold('Please enter an email address');
$('.manyTextFields').placehold('All get the same text & behavior.');
```

Comment: hm, i was thinking there had to be a more efficient way than what i did.

Thanks for your answer and the code suggestion ^^

Comment: @kyushiro Also see the plugin suggestion!

Comment: @tomalak I didn't really consider the plugin option since i had not yet explored this aspect of JQuery development, yet the code you posted makes it seem eerily easy. Thanks again for the heads up :)

Comment: Out of couriousity, would putting a placeholder in using this function  make the placeholder itself a value?  If so, would you have to modify validation at that point?

Comment: @Brad: Yes, of course it would make it a value. The solution would either be to remove the defaults via a submit callback on each form field or to ignore default values on the server side.